# Seahub fails to run initial start with ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, seafile-server

I'm currently trying to install seafile 7.1.4 on a Raspberry Pi 4 following the official guide (https://download.seafile.com/published/seafile-manual/deploy/using_mysql.md). The setup went smoothly, but when I try to start the seahub (./seahub start) for the first time I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "check_init_admin.py", line 351, in <module>
    rpc = RPC()
  File "check_init_admin.py", line 284, in __init__
    import ccnet
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ccnet'
```

I've been on google for the past two hours, but can't find a solution to this problem. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue.  There's a bug in the 7.1.4 package.  Seafile uses some local site packages.  They (apparently) used to be under ${INSTALLPATH}/seafile/lib/python**3.6**/site-packages, now the are under ${INSTALLPATH}/seafile/lib/python**3.7**/site-packages

To fix:
open seahub.sh in the editor of your choice.
find the line that says:

`export PYTHONPATH=${INSTALLPATH}/seafile/lib/python3.6/site-packages:${INSTALLPATH}/seafile/lib64/python3.6/site-packages:${INSTALLPATH}/seahub:${INSTALLPATH}/seahub/thirdpart:$PYTHONPATH`

change it to read:

`export PYTHONPATH=${INSTALLPATH}/seafile/lib/python3.7/site-packages:${INSTALLPATH}/seafile/lib64/python3.7/site-packages:${INSTALLPATH}/seahub:${INSTALLPATH}/seahub/thirdpart:$PYTHONPATH`